# Why is the review queue empty?

Tags: discussion, flagging

The review queue is a filter, which shows a list of questions with a certain criteria. The idea is not to show the entire list of questions, but only these which are flagged by a group member for later review. A look into the close-view queue have shown, that it's empty. That means, there are no questions which can be closed. Is this a malfunction or is it normal?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is just because *Robotics* doesn't get that many questions.  With only 2.1 questions per day according to Area51 (https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020/robotics), our few moderators can keep up.  I don't know how many questions the "real" *Stack Exchange* site gets, but I'm sure it's a lot more.

Comment: Probably, the “real” Stackexchange is referencing to the inbox of academic publishing houses like Elsevier and Springer who have a review queue which allows them to maintain a high reputation.